# How to achieve where in query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I just successfully imported my data to ES, e,g. It looks like this:

```
"activity": 'viewed',
"sessionId": "000000143198107b3fe510b041138cd33fdd9252aab9808c",
"campaign_id":""
,

"activity": 'campaign_viewed',
"sessionId": "000000143198107b3fe510b041138cd33fdd9252aab9808c",
"campaign_id":"my_campaign"
```

As you can see, the two entries has the same `sessionId`, and since the second entry has a `campaign_id`, i will assume the first activity(viewed) is also generated from the campaign.
So how can i do count like:
(count the activities that are generated from campaign):

```
count(activity)
where sessionId in (select sessionid from index where campaign_id="m_campaign") ?
```

or to put in another way:

> "count all the activities within the same session only if in this
>   session there is an 'activity=campaign_viewed'.

I know ES will have aggregation available soon. but not sure whether that would solve this kind of issue.

P.S. The possible solution I am thinking of is:
1. get data into bucket by sessionId, meantime doing count, and max on the campaignId field
so that i can have group of data like:

```
6, session1, my_campaign_1
5, session2, my_campaign_1
6, session1, null (assume its the result of max on empty string)
```

2 then do another aggregation on the campaign_d field of the bucket data generated in step1
and exclude all those data whose campaign_id is null. the the final result would be:

```
11, my_campiagn_1
```

But I am not sure whether this could be done in ES.

Thanks much!
Chen

Comment: Another way I could think of is to emit a campaign child document which contains the sessionId, campaign_id info. Then doing some kind of join to get the stat over the parent document only when sessionId exists in the child document? Not sure how I can do this..

Comment: To those who might be interested in such problem, my final solution is to use storm topology to do the first level aggregation by session before committing to ES: whenever I write into ES, i will read out session if exists, and then add the campaign id as a field to it. Then I can use aggregation to get the final stat I want.

Comment: Take a look at: 
[Finding Multiple Exact Values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html)